# Use constant in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Many places in Storyboard using the same values i.e. for x coordinate of views. Am I able to control these values together by adjusting one constant from code? Can I define a value in constants.h and refer to it in the Storyboard?

Comment: I think that is still not possible. Same for color constants. I would be great though

Comment: I think it isn't possible up until now, I want to know the answer to same.